# What does X1 mean in the statistics?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

I'm trying to refresh my knowledge in mathematical statistics since my university days. I'm mostly using Russian resources but assume that it's applicable for others.

What isn't really clear for me is the meaning of the $X_1$. For example, in the book https://mipt.ru/diht/students/courses/mathematical_statistics.pdf we have a definition of *unbiased estimator* and an example of applying it to a *sample mean* on 11th page. I will duplicate the example here:

$$ E_\theta \bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum{E_\theta X_i} = E_\theta X_1 $$

The last transition isn't obvious to me. Perhaps, $X_1$ means the first element from the sample but I don't get why we chose exactly the first element and not, for instance, the 2nd.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it means the first element. I assume $E_{\theta}X_i$ is the same for all $i$, so you could pick any one, but if you picked, say, $X_7$ your statement wouldn't make sense when $n \le 6$.

Answer (score 1):

$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables. It follows that the expected values are equal, i.e. $\operatorname EX_1=\ldots=\operatorname EX_n$. So we can take any of the expected values and the result would be the same. In your example, $\operatorname EX_1$ is chosen.

Comment: They do not even need to be independent or have the same distribution - just have the same expectation